# How to to tie the execution of one process to another inside a loop in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, popen

How can I keep a loop going, while having some processes that are waiting for others inside the loop? (see the code below for clarification, it makes more sense to explain in code)

```
for i in range(0, len(my_list), batch_size):
    current_batch = my_list[i:i+batch_size]
    download_processes = [Popen('do stuff')] # NOT ACTUAL CODE. This downloads files.
    _ = [p.wait() for p in download_processes] # wait until all files above download before executing the code below 

    more_processes = [Popen('do stuff')] # NOT ACTUAL CODE. This zips the downloaded files
    # execute yet more processes (that process the zips files) when "more_processes" end, but keep the loop going to start downloading more files
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a pool
2. Use loop inside pool for the batch
3. Use result = pool.map_async() with your target method

4.Do result.get(timeout) or result.wait()

5. If you get timeout or after your condition is met, return and break out of the while loop and pool.close, terminate and then join.

```
def process_url(url):
  # call url and process data
  
  pass

def pool_handler():
    with Pool() as p:
     for i in range(0, len(my_list), batch_size):
      current_batch_urls = my_list[i:i+batch_size]
    
      # this will create processes and process url
      r = p.map_async(process_url, current_batch_urls)
      r. wait()#wait for each batch

   #outside loop 
    p.close()
    p.join()#wait until all processes are done

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool_handler()
```

Comment: See I don't think this code does what I want because it seems like it downloads and processes the data, then moves on to download and process again and so on. I would like to download, start processing, and start the next batch of downloading at the same time as I'm processing.

Comment: The urls is a list. Ensure the subset of list is passed each time. See the code above. I've updated it

Answer (score -1):

You can use `multiprocessing` module to achieve this

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time, requests

urls = ["file_url1","file_url2","file_url3"]


def download_file(url):
    return requests.get(url).content.strip()

def process_url(url):
    file_content = download_file(url)
    # Process File content 

def pool_handler():
    p = Pool(2)
    p.map(process_url, urls)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool_handler()
```

Comment: But I read that asyncio is not well suited for CPU bound tasks. I specifically would like to use multiprocessing if possible

Comment: You are downloading files, it's IO bound task

Comment: Right but I'm also processing files

Comment: You are downloading the file and processing the contents of the downloaded file?

Comment: that's the `# execute yet more processes (that process the zips files)...` that I mentioned in the last line of code as a comment